# Make HttpWebResponse (Header) timeout independent?

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I make POST request via my web-client and then have to wait until I receive the response from server. The issue is timeout (WebException), when i use

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponseWithTimeout();
```

I can't specify timeout(Currently default: 100 sec.) or use infinite timeout here due to some requirements. Please suggest any solution to be able to wait until I receive the response. It should also work if the server stops working at any stage. I mean to say, if I make timeout infinite and close the server then the web client keeps waiting and does not know that the server is stopped somehow?

Comment: Can we see your "closing" code ?

Comment: Well, in real scenario, don't have closing code. Just for testing I stopped the server by myself while timeout was set to infinite. and client remained in waiting state...

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to wait for infinity but you can't, but still want to?

Comment: Sorry, I try again..I want to wait until I receive response. How much i need to wait, I dn't know because it depends on server. On my own, i thought to use infinite timeout(That worked right but in that case if something wrong happens on server then client will always be waiting for response). I need other suggestions to solve this problem..